# incorrectly checks the response c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, call, messagebox

I have a code that gets a response from the POST request:

```
//Запрос авторизации бухаря
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://clannr.org/scripts/login/auth.php");
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "user=" + Login.Text + "&password=" + Password.Text + "&version=13";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

But when checking the response:

```
        Match match = regex.Match(responseFromServer);

if (match.Success)
        {
            var input = responseFromServer;
            var split = input.Split(':');
            var final = split[3];
            ProcessStartInfo mcStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("javaw", "-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -cp \"" + appData + "\\.ClanNR\\bin\\minecraft1.jar;" + appData + "\\.ClanNR\\bin\\jinput.jar;" + appData + "\\.ClanNR\\bin\\lwjgl.jar;" + appData + "\\.ClanNR\\bin\\lwjgl_util.jar \" -Djava.library.path=\"" + appData + "\\.ClanNR\\bin\\natives\" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft" + " " + username + " " + final + " " + server1);
            Process.Start(mcStartInfo);
            this.Close();



        }

        else if (responseFromServer == " Bad Login")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Uncorrect login/password!");
        }
        else if (responseFromServer == " Old version")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Launcher is old!");
        }
```

My code called just 2 functions, i.e. show 2 MessageBox

How to fix it?

UPDATED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if, say, `responseFromServer` variable equals to `"Foo"` then it fits both conditions, because it's not equal to `" Bad Login"` and not equal to `" Old version"`

What you probably want is `else if`:

```
    if (responseFromServer != " Bad Login")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Uncorrect login/password!");
    }
    else if (responseFromServer != " Old version")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Launcher is old!");
    }
```

Or probably you wanted `==` instead of `!=`

```
if (responseFromServer == " Bad Login")
```

So it's your job now to find out what you really want to achieve.

PS: are spaces in the beginning of both strings intended?

Comment: "PS: are spaces in the beginning of both strings intended?"
Yes, my response have spaces

Comment: @user1798736: and what is the question now?

Comment: Sorry, I am Russian.

I updated the first post. What was wrong?

Comment: @user1798736: you have 3 IFs. So?

Comment: Давай на русском. Код не работает :)

Comment: @user1798736: На описание проблемы "не работает" есть только один возможный ответ - "ну так почини его". Что такое "не работает"?

Comment: Если я ставлю ==, то MessageBox вообще не появляется.

Comment: Могу я вам как-нибудь показать код?

Comment: @user1798736: ну т.е. ты вообще наугад ставишь операторы и ожидаешь, что всё магически взлетит? Если не появляются - значит переменная не равна ни одному из строковых литералов.

Comment: Невозможно) А вот если ставить !=, то работает всё, кроме того, где написано else if

Comment: @user1798736: "Невозможно" - проблема в том, что C# не врёт :-) Если он работает так, как работает - значит возможно. Код всегда работает правильно, просто ты ожидаешь от него чего-то другого. Возьми дебаггер и посмотри, что там в переменной в действительности лежит

Comment: Я новичок в этом деле. Так вот же, в 1 посту написан весь код проверки, изменён так, как вы сказали, но он не показывает МесседжБокс :)

Comment: @user1798736: тогда самым оптимальным вариантом будет взять книжку по шарпу и попробовать его поучить, чтобы писать код осознанно, а не наугад - как видишь, метод научного тыка не работает.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я учусь на практике, поэтому мне не до книжек :)

Comment: @user1798736: метод "некогда пилу точить - надо лес валить" не работает, когда нет базовых знаний. Так что открывай книжки, учи основы и потом возвращайся к практике.

Comment: Короче говоря, когда я ставлю else перед if, то даже если я введу правильный пароль, вызовет 1 оператор без else

Comment: Уткни мне на ошибку, и я пойду учить книжки)

Comment: @user1798736: твоя ошибка в том, что ты думаешь, что в переменной лежит то, чего там не лежит. Я выше уже советовал взять дебагер и убедиться в этом, а не продолжать гадать.

Comment: It was kinda fresh, you know. )

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `!=` operator means not-equal.
Correct me if i'm wrong, but I think you wanted to use `==`.

```
if (responseFromServer == " Bad Login")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Uncorrect login/password!");
}

else if (responseFromServer == " Old version")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Launcher is old!");
}
```

Secondly, you should use else if. if the first condition is true, then it won't check the other.