# If not called. c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [incorrectly checks the response c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223602/incorrectly-checks-the-response-c-sharp)

I have a code:

```
Match match = regex.Match(responseFromServer);
if (match.Success)
{
    var input = responseFromServer;
    var split = input.Split(':');
    var final = split[3];
    ProcessStartInfo mcStartInfo = new Shitocode;
    Process.Start(mcStartInfo);
    this.Close();
}
else if (responseFromServer == " Bad Login")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Uncorrect login/password!");
}
else if (responseFromServer == " Old version")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Launcher is old!");
}
```

Why there is no message box showing in the last two inspections?

I have tried to do things differently:

```
if (match.Success)
{
    var input = responseFromServer;
    var split = input.Split(':');
    var final = split[3];
    ProcessStartInfo mcStartInfo = new Shitocode;
    Process.Start(mcStartInfo);
    this.Close();
}
else if (responseFromServer.Equals("Bad Login"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Uncorrect login/password!");
}
else if (responseFromServer.Equals("Old Version"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Launcher is old!");
}
```

I enter the wrong password, but does not open the messagebox

Comment: add a debug statement to check what the `responseFromServer` is: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer);` Then you can check if your else if statements are good.

Comment: Are you sure about the responses? Maybe the server does not respons `"Bad login` or `"Old Version"`. Try debugging that code.

Comment: So, what does happen, what is the response from  the server?

Comment: Yes, responseFromServer = " Bad login"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your **responseFromServer** does not match the values you are checking (Bad Login, and Old Version).
Try to add another ***else*** at the end of the ***if*** sequence and look what you've got.

```
if (match.Success)
{
   //your code
}
else if (responseFromServer.Equals("Bad Login"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Uncorrect login/password!");
}
else if (responseFromServer.Equals("Old Version"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Launcher is old!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot login, unknown response: " + responseFromServer)
}
```

**EDIT** after comment

If you do not the exact message, but you know that it has to contain some exact string, you could change the two `responseFromServer.Equals()` to `responseFromServer.Contains()`

Comment: Ok. I'm wrote wrong password and press button. I see messagebox with text "Cannot login, unknown response: Bad Login"

Comment: I added a suggestion for how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = instxtbox.Text;
        string[] s1 = new string[3];
        s1[0] = " ";
        s1[1] = " ";
        s1[2] = " ";

        string[] portion = s.Split(s1, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(portion[2]);

        string reg = portion[1];



        if (reg == "ax")
            axtxtbox.Text = portion[2];

        else if (reg == "bx")
            bxtxtbox.Text = portion[2];
        else if (reg == "cx")
            cxtxtbox.Text = portion[2];
        else if (reg == "dx")
            dxtxtbox.Text = portion[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a breakingpoint, go through the code and check the Value of `responseFromServer` Copy this in the two cases and compare it in your code, i noticed you have whitespaces in the 1st code part before " Bad Login", but im not sure its the reason anyway.